# Content is not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Unfortunately, I'm unable to understand where there is realization mistake.
The main application window should show a content from view model (HomeView.xaml)
Could you advice, what I has done incorrect?
Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq3PS.png

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using ohb.MVVM.ViewModel;

namespace ohb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = new HomeViewModel();  

        }

    // Moveable window
        private void WindowMouseMoving(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                this.DragMove();
            }
        }
  
    // Exit button
    private void CloseButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Close();
    }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ohb.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ohb"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ohb.MVVM.ViewModel"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ohb.MVVM.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="600" Width="920"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Background="Transparent"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    MouseMove="WindowMouseMoving">

<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

    
        
    <Border Background="#2f4f4f"
        CornerRadius="30">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Application"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Foreground="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">


            <RadioButton Content="Home"
                Height="50"
                Foreground="White"
                FontSize="14"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                IsChecked="True"
                Command="{Binding HomeViewCommand}"/>

            <RadioButton Content="Menu"
                Height="50"
                Foreground="White"
                FontSize="14"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                Command="{Binding DiscoveryViewCommand}"/>

            <RadioButton Content="Settings"
                Height="50"
                Foreground="White"
                FontSize="14"
                Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"/>

            <RadioButton Content="Exit"
                Click="CloseButtonClick"
                Height="50"
                Foreground="White"
                FontSize="14"
                        Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"/>

        </StackPanel>

            <TextBox Width="250"
                 Height="40"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="5"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTheme}"/>

            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="10"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>



        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ohb.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ohb"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ohb.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ohb.MVVM.View"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MenuButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/TextBoxTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
                <view:HomeView/>
        </DataTemplate>

         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MenuButtonTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
           x:Key="MenuButtonTheme"> 
        <Style.Setters> 
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

              
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>
        
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3b6363"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

TextBoxTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           x:Key="TextBoxTheme">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="10"
                Background="#3b6363"
                Width="200" Height="40">

                        <Grid>
                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="1"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     Padding="5"
                                     Foreground="White"
                     x:Name="SearchBox"/>

                <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Text="Search"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                Foreground="DarkGray"
                Grid.Column="1"
                FontSize="12">

                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchBox}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>

                </TextBlock>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

ObservableObject.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ohb.Core
{

    class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        } 


    }

}
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ohb.Core
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;
 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
 
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }
 
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }
 
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using ohb.Core;

namespace ohb.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        
        public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }


        public HomeViewModel HomeVM { get; set; }

              
        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView 
        {
            get { return _currentView; } 
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            HomeVM = new HomeViewModel();

            
            CurrentView = HomeVM;
            

            HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVM;
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
using ohb.Core;

namespace ohb.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class HomeViewModel
    {

    }
}
```

HomeView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ohb.MVVM.View.HomeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ohb.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ohb.MVVM.View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:HomeViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Discover"
    Foreground="White"
    FontSize="28"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="0,0,0,20"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Border Width="400"
            Height="200">

        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,2">
            <GradientStop Color="#5bc3ff" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#3aa0ff" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>

        <Border.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="10"
                       RadiusY="10"
                       Rect="0,0,400,200"/>
        </Border.Clip>

        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="World leader&#x0a;in global"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="28"
                   Margin="20,10,10,0"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Get started"
                   Foreground="White"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Margin="20,10,10,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>

        </Border>   

<Border Width="200" 
    Height="200"
    CornerRadius="10"
    Margin="45,0,0,0">

        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,2">
            <GradientStop Color="#5bc3ff" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#3aa0ff" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>

</Border>
    </StackPanel>


<StackPanel>

<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>


    <TextBlock Text="most watched"
    Foreground="White"
    FontSize="20"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border Width="150"
            Height="150"
            Background="#844eff"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Margin="0"/>

        <Border Width="150"
            Height="150"
            Background="Red"
            CornerRadius="10"/>

        <Border Width="150"
            Height="150"
            Background="Gray"
            CornerRadius="10"/>

        <Border Width="150"
            Height="150"
            Background="Green"
            CornerRadius="10"/>

    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: why do you set `this.DataContext = new HomeViewModel(); ` when window expect MainViewModel for DataContext ??

Answer (score 0):

A UserControl must not explictly set its own DataContext, as you have declared it in HomeView.xaml as

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:HomeViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This assignment breaks the [value inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/property-value-inheritance?view=netdesktop-6.0) of the DataContext property, which is essential to make the below DataTemplate work. Instead of getting the current data item as its DataContext, the control would always use the one that was explicitly set.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
    <view:HomeView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

So simply remove the DataContext assignment from the UserControl's XAML.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take this into account. Regretfully, this didn't help resolving the underlying issue.